# (LibGDX) - getting NullPointerException when calling my character's render method

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-engine

can't figure out why this is happening, it was fine before. Basically the game starts up and displays for a second, I can see my tilemap and character then it crashes, LogCat gives me a nullpointer for Spritebatch, and the first thing it points to in my code is my renderFrog() method. Here's the relevant code (im aware its messy but im just trying to hack it together, clean implementation and class hierarchy will come after i get this basic working prototype):

```
@Override
// my create method, just loading an animation in. this worked previously, i haven't changed anything on it.    


public void create() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    textureAtlas = new   TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/froganimate.atlas"));
    TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    walkLeftFrames[i] = textureAtlas.findRegion("000" + (i + 7));
                    walkLeftFrames[i].flip(true, false);

                }
    walkLeftAnimation = new Animation(0.16f, walkLeftFrames);

    TextureRegion[] walkRightFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++) {
                    walkRightFrames[i1] = textureAtlas.findRegion("000" + (i1 + 7));

                }
    walkRightAnimation = new Animation(0.04f, walkLeftFrames);
```

}

```
//the render method. as far as i know, i didn't change anything on it since it broke.

@Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        updateFrog(stateTime);

        cam.update();
        renderer.setView(cam);

        renderer.render();
        renderFrog(stateTime);
    }

// the update frog method. the keystates are activated by touches on the screen

    private void updateFrog(float deltaTime){
        if(deltaTime == 0) return;
        frog.frogTime += deltaTime;


        if (keystates.get(Keystates.LEFT))
        {
            frog.state = Frog.State.WalkingL;
            frog.velocity.x = -Frog.MAX_VELOCITY;
        }
        if (keystates.get(Keystates.RIGHT))
        {
            frog.state = Frog.State.WalkingR;
            frog.velocity.x = Frog.MAX_VELOCITY;
        }
        if (keystates.get(Keystates.UP))
        {
            frog.state = Frog.State.WalkingU;
            frog.velocity.y = -Frog.MAX_VELOCITY;
        }
        if (keystates.get(Keystates.DOWN))
        {
            frog.state = Frog.State.WalkingD;
            frog.velocity.y = Frog.MAX_VELOCITY;
        }

        if(Math.abs(frog.velocity.x) < 1 & Math.abs(frog.velocity.y) < 1)
        {
            frog.state = Frog.State.Standing;

        }

        {
        if(Math.abs(frog.velocity.x) > Frog.MAX_VELOCITY) {
            frog.velocity.x = Math.signum(frog.velocity.x) * Frog.MAX_VELOCITY;
    }
        if(Math.abs(frog.velocity.x) < .005f){
            frog.velocity.x = 0;




        }
        if(Math.abs(frog.velocity.y) > Frog.MAX_VELOCITY) {
            frog.velocity.y = Math.signum(frog.velocity.y) * Frog.MAX_VELOCITY;
    }
        if(Math.abs(frog.velocity.y) < .005f){
            frog.velocity.y = 0;
        }

        frog.velocity.scl(deltaTime);
        frog.position.add(frog.velocity);
        frog.velocity.scl(1/deltaTime);






    }
    }
}

private void renderFrog(float deltaTime){


    TextureRegion frogregion = null;


    switch(frog.state){
    case WalkingU: frogregion = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(frog.frogTime); break;
    case WalkingD: frogregion = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(frog.frogTime); break;
    case WalkingL: frogregion = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(frog.frogTime); break;
    case WalkingR: frogregion = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(frog.frogTime); break;
    case Standing: frogregion = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(frog.frogTime); break;
    }


    frogregion = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(frog.frogTime)

    SpriteBatch batch = renderer.getSpriteBatch();
    batch.begin();
// THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS      
batch.draw(frogregion, frog.position.x, frog.position.y, Frog.WIDTH, Frog.HEIGHT);

    batch.end();
}
```

pre-edit: i tried intitializing "frogregion" in the create() method, but that didn't change anything. Help!

Comment: I also just commented out all of my character movement code. so that the entire game is just rendering the character on screen. still crashes, pointing to my render methods. if it means anything, my character does appear in game and animates for about two frames, then it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2 animations you have:

```
TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

TextureRegion[] walkRightFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++) {
```

you create an array of 4 TextureRegions but only create the first 3 (i=0, i=1 and i=2 because the condition is i<3). Change it to <4:

```
TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

TextureRegion[] walkRightFrames = new TextureRegion[4];
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; i1++) {
```

(Or if they are only 3 frames per animation, then change all those 4 to 3).

Comment: i dont know whether to be happy or amazed at how small and stupid of an error this was, i remember changing this as well. Yeah I was changing it down to 3 frames. Thanks so much man. and how it ran two frames then stopped makes perfect sense.